# iOS Health compatible body scale – without obliged manufacturer account creation?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, health.app

I'm looking for a **smart body scale** that connects via Bluetooth to my iOS device, but *does not* require to create accounts. Just a simple app that shows you the nitty gritty (BMI, fat, water, etc.) when you step on the scale, but stores data on your (i)Phone.

Seems hard to find.

*I simply don't get why all these scale manufactures need you to create a account. I have no interest in sharing that data with them. I also see no need for them to store this.*

Comment: Perhaps an opening for you to write one...

Comment: @SolarMike  lol. Yeah I’m considering just hacking a scale. But ...